# Confusion using xdebug_debug_zval between refcount and is_ref

Tags: php, xdebug, php-internals

I'm using `xdebug_debug_zval` in order to understand how references changed between PHP 5 and PHP 7.

```
<?php
$array = array('k1', 'k2', 'k3');

echo PHP_VERSION. '<br/>';
foreach ($array as &$ref) {
}
unset($ref);

xdebug_debug_zval('ref');
xdebug_debug_zval('array');
```

PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 :

```
5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14
array:
(refcount=1, is_ref=0),
array (size=3)
  0 => (refcount=1, is_ref=0),string 'k1' (length=2)
  1 => (refcount=1, is_ref=0),string 'k2' (length=2)
  2 => (refcount=1, is_ref=0),string 'k3' (length=2)
```

PHP 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 :

```
7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3
ref:
(refcount=0, is_ref=0)*uninitialized*
array:
(refcount=1, is_ref=1)
array (size=3)
  0 => (refcount=1, is_ref=1)string 'k1' (length=2)
  1 => (refcount=1, is_ref=1)string 'k2' (length=2)
  2 => (refcount=1, is_ref=1)string 'k3' (length=2)
```

Why in PHP 7 `is_ref` is equal to 1 knowing that I have unset the reference and according to [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php) ? :

> Note that if "refcount" is 1, "is_ref" is always FALSE.

**PS** : OPcache is disabled (`opcache.enable=0`).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, since PHP 7 changed the way how variables are handled internally, it's not really possible for `xdebug_debug_zval()` to give fully accurate results any more.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you give me some sources in order I understand the way it changed?